# Expected value in budget constraint

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimization, risk-aversion, dynamic-optimization

I have been reading [this paper](https://www.frbsf.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019-10-17-Liu-Schmid-Yaron-paper.pdf) by Yang Liu, Lukas Schmid and Amir Yaron, which contains a very elegant mechanism that generates an endogenous liquidity premium for US government debt. However, I got confused by something.

In that paper, households have liquidity needs that arrive with probability $\lambda_t$ with magnitude $\xi_t$. To meet these liquidity needs, they need to sell off some of their assets. In so doing, they incur a cost $\nu_t$. This cost then enters the budget constraint (page 9, first equation). But from the first equation on page 11, it is clear this cost is an *average* (averaged across shock magnitudes $\xi_t \sim \Phi_\xi$).

The households are not risk-neutral, so they should care about the variance of the costs, but implicitly the authors seem to be imposing that they don't. I emailed the authors about this, but never received a response. I would be very grateful if someone could point out what I am missing. Thanks in advance!